# Why I'm getting this exception?

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

I'm trying to reverse a string through the Windows form but for any reason `for` loop is giving an exception when I'm executing the code.

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference is not set to an instance of an object

**Button_Click event**

```
string input=textBox1.Text;
input=Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
string output="";

if(textBox1.Text=="")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Sorry! You have not given any input for perform action");
}
else
{
    try{

        for(int i=input.Length-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
            output= output+input[i];
        }

            textBox2.Text=output;
            }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(""+ex);
        }
    }
 }
```

While same logic is working perfectly with console application. I know I'm missing very basic thing but at the moment I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Why are you using input for both textbox.text and console.readline?

Comment: @MarcGravell I've been left the practice of my coding due to some reasons but now I'm back with it. Can you give a better program explanation for my code with your answer.

Comment: You are asking for a value from the console in a windows forms application. It just isn't available in that type of project, so you can't access the console object and are getting an error.

Comment: @avirk I don't understand what you are asking in your comment, above-and-beyond what I've already written...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In a winform, `Console.ReadLine()` returns `null` (because there *is no console*). Likewise, `Convert.ToString((string)null)` returns `null`. And you can't call `.Length` (in the `for`) on a `null`. Key pieces of code:

```
input=Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
...
for(int i=input.Length-1; i>=0; i--)
```

Also, as a minor point: building up a string via concatenation is very inefficient.

Comment: Dang, I was feeling really smug for figuring that out. Then I saw your answer. Gonna go cry now.

Comment: Yep now I got what mistake I was making. Very foolish thing to use console with Windows form :P

Answer (score 2):

Marc pointed your error correctly. But also I'd refactored your code to (as I understand you want to put reversed input into textBox2):

```
string input = textBox1.Text;

if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Sorry! You have not given any input for perform action");
    return;
}

textBox2.Text = new String(input.Reverse().ToArray());
```

Comment: Note that properly reversing a string is tricky, and cannot be done simply by reversing the characters unless we know that it isn't making use of combining marks/diacritics, or surrogate-pairs. But what you have is identical to the question, I'll grant.

Comment: @MarcGravell agree, but this gives OP desired output :)

Answer (score 1):

i think it should be:

```
output += input[i];
```

and an easy approach to do this would be this method

```
public static string ReverseString(string s)
{
    char[] arr = s.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(arr);
    return new string(arr);
}
```

Comment: just a typing mistake when posted my answer but in real code its the same as you suggested

Comment: @avirk that is why copy/paste is useful ;p

Comment: @MarcGravell next time I'll do that :P

Comment: Note that *properly* reversing a string is tricky, and cannot be done *simply* by reversing the characters unless we know that it isn't making use of combining marks/diacritics, or surrogate-pairs. But what you have is identical to the question, I'll grant.

Answer (score 0):

`input` may doesn’t have a value or may just have a single element in it BUT you are trying to access it through `input[1]` that means the second element of it which will give you NullPointer exception.

```
output= output+input[1]; //I guess you did this by mistake
```

it should be this way.

```
for(int i=input.Length-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        output= output+input[i]; //Change '1' with 'i'
    }
```

Hope this will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `Console` functions in WinForms? 
Your problem is in this line which is leading to other forthcoming errors.

`input=Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());`

Change it this way:

```
string input=textBox1.Text;
input=Convert.ToString(input); //However i don't think you even require this line
```

Comment: 15 minutes later i would cast a glance on the highest upvoted answer before i would answer a question myself.

Comment: textBox.Text always contains non-null string